# check timestamps from text file and copy files to location

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code here which takes timestamps of files referenced in this text file, which works as expected and outputs timestamps.

What I want to if a timestamp on that file has changed then take a copy of those files to a backup location.
Code to copy files would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import shutil
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.c:
    with open(args.c, 'r') as file:
        dest = '/home/admin/backup'
        filelist = file.read().split('\n')
        for file1 in filelist:
            if file1:
                shutil.copy(file1.strip(), dest)
else:
    print("exiting due to error")


if args.l:
        f = open('config.dat','r')
        list_contents = f.read()
        print(list_contents)
        f.close()

#Take all timestamps from config.dat
import os
import datetime
f = open('config.dat','r')
list_contents = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()
for a in list_contents:
    b = os.path.getmtime(a)
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(b))
```

Config file:

```
file1
file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` as a cache, with the file name as a key and the timestamp is the data. Since your list content is only the file name, you need to get the timestamp:
`cache = dict((file, os.path.getmtime(file)) for file in list_content)`

Then when you read your file again, you can compare the timestamps and if they are different, you can save it. `if cache[file] != os.path.getmtime(file): save_data(file)`

Comment: Okay this sounds perfect.  I modified the code above to explain in more detail..  Any pointers for my code above on how this would work

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for assist... modified this slightly:
cache = dict((a, os.path.getmtime(a)) for a in list_contents) 

maybe got this confused here?

Comment: Why using `a` ? It is less readable. It is only a variable name so, `file` is more accurate. `file_name` would be also better. Remove your former loop `for a in list_contents:`, this loop is now directly into the dict constructor.